# I need a drag and drop control for C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a control for C# that can contain other controls, takes care of layout and allows drag and drop rearranging of the layout order.

Simularly to the way the iphone/ipod allows you to rearrange apps.

Thanks.

Comment: I've seen this (with layout etc) for WPF/Silverlight, but not so often for winforms...

Comment: I'm not so I sure I want to develop this app with WPF, since I have no knowledge of it and learning it would take some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using something like [DockPanelSuite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite) as a basis might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can implement your own easily, using FlowLayoutPanel and MouseUp, MouseDown, MouseMove  events of the controls where you change the Location property approximately and FlowLayoutPanel should handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own.  You can intiate a DragDrop operation (usually in OnMouseDown) by calling the DoDragDrop() method of your control.  You can override the OnDragOver and OnDragDrop methods of your controls which will accept a dragged object.  Resizing is already built in, you just need to set the properties (given, it can be a bit of a pain.)