# Winforms drag and drop labels in the form

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have few lables in windows form. I want let user can drag and drop anywhere in the form. So that I can store their position in registry or database to restore them next time.
 I read the question
[I need a drag and drop control for C# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549911/i-need-a-drag-and-drop-control-for-c-winforms)

But it didnt help me properly when I used DoDragDrop method on mousedown of the labels and OnDragOver  event of the form.

**Edit**

To store the postion and restore the position is not I am looking here, Only the simple code how to drag/drop labels in winforms without using libraries or third party controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this might help:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/Draganddropimagetoanotherwindow.htm

Although this is for Image but I hope the same can be done for labels too.

:)